# Converting excel spreadsheets to HTML

Tags: html, excel, joomla, converters

I have a customer who asked me to make a website.
Now I have the basic website running (on joomla) but now he wants his pricelist pages displayed on there (seems reasonable)

How can i import import Excel file into as an array and display on html page with tags

Grtz,
Thomas

Edit:
perhaps something from pdf to html since I can create pdf files from it...

Comment: Try this: http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/f/blfaqexceltable.htm

Comment: That... doesnt really work, the generated html is 259909 lines, so big that in dreamweaver my scroll button just breaks and it creates 2 images of everything where one has a really bad quality and then some strange if statement descides that IN EVERY BROWSER EXCEPT IE it should show the crap quality image...

Comment: How many records are in the spreadsheet? What does the client intend a visitor to do with the information? Slapping 10,000 prices on a page is not particularly useful for a user. Knowing what you want to do with the price sheet will have a direct effect on what the best solution is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel saves spreadsheets in XML format, so you can use XSLT to transform your customer's spreadsheet into HTML.  The Excel XML format is somewhat obtuse, but if you only need to grab certain pieces of critical data, it's a reasonable solution.  Here's some information about the Excel XML format, though Googling will probably reveal more:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx

And here's the W3C standard for XSL 1.0 (I doubt you would need 2.0 features, which are more complex, for this job):

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt

XSLT is a declarative XML transformation language, which you would have to learn the fundamentals of for this job, but it's a very useful tool if you deal with XML generally, and the additional virtue of this solution is that it is repeatable (when the customer's data changes).

EDIT:  Here's an XSLT tutorial, which is obviously a more friendly introduction to the language than the W3C standard:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that might just be to complicated for me :/

Answer (score 1):

If the price list only gets updated every now and again, can you not simply save the spreadsheet file as an HTML page from within Excel? This will give you some pretty nasty HTML (thanks MS), but it's a good starting point.

(As JollyMorphic points out, you can also transform Excel's XML, but that's quite heavy duty for what you appear to need).

Comment: I think I'll end up converting it to images or do some last tries converting from pdf to html, the html files alone are over 16mb, converted to images I can still load everything way faster

Comment: There are some online tools out there which help clean up HTML, you might want to try those (for example, a web-enabled version of HTML Tidy: http://valet.htmlhelp.com/tidy/ ) Putting everything up as an image won't help the site's accessibility or search rankings.