# jquery export table to excel changes the value in exponential form

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I Have a jquery export table to excel code. But the problem is that it changes the value is export file of xls. my table td has a value 810101E001 when I export it it changes the value like 8.10E+06.

please provide me solution what to do now.

http://jsfiddle.net/wVejP/773/

jquery code is

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not really exporting the table to Excel from what I can see, you're exporting it to HTML inside Excel (i.e. it's still coded as a web page inside the file and you get warnings when saving / loading it).

In any case Excel is interpreting that field as a number, in order to stop it doing so you must set the style of that cell to indicate that it's text. However since you're not translating the HTML to the internal Excel XML syntax I'm not sure how to do that (for what it's worth I believe this is correct `<Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String" ...>...</Data></Cell>`).

So either you need to translate the HTML fully to Excel XML or you could just quote all cell data, something like:

```
contents = table.innerHTML
                .replace(/(<td[^>]*>)/gi, '$1"')
                .replace(/(<\/td[^>]*>)/gi, '"$1');
```

But that quotes *everything* which isn't good either, ideally you want some way to tag certain cells as text and quote them -- but if you can't do that automatically you're as well just putting the quotes into the HTML itself. If you know the position of the cell you could do it that way by just quoting a single cell (in your example it's the first `TD` so it's easy).

But really you need to convert the HTML to Excel XML to do this properly (you'll still need to know which cells you don't want to be interpreted as numbers). See this answer for starting points for that: [Converting excel spreadsheets to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402988/converting-excel-spreadsheets-to-html)